# How to up update eternal html file after ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I loaded an html file using AJAX, and now I want to update it in my folder after doing modifications on it, is that possible ?

Thanks

Comment: Not without a server-side component.

Comment: Huh, that's what I thought, thanks anyway